# Does Salesforce Visual Workflow support swim lanes?

Tags: visual-workflow

I would like to know if Visual Workflow support swim lanes? If not, is there any (free) utility that can be used to generate flows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Visual Workflow is not meant to be used as a diagram designer.

A quick google search would bring you many results but I usually go for http://www.gliffy.com/